# D3js with element base on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing a graph where the elements may differ, for example:

```
[
{id: 1, type: "type1", name: "Some name" },
{id: 2, type: "type2", name: "Some name" },
{id: 3, type: "type2", name: "Some name" },
{id: 4, type: "type1", name: "Some name" }
]
```

Now if the element is of type=type1 would I like it to add

```
<g>
<rect width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
<text x="0" y="0" fill="red">Some name</text>
</g>
```

if type=type2

```
<g>
<rect width="10" height="10" stroke="blue" />
<rect x="15" y="15" width="10" height="10" stroke="blue" />
<text x="0" y="0" fill="red">Some name</text>
</g>
```

How would I be able to do this using D3js?

Comment: If the number of elements and elements themselves are different for all the types, I would group the original data by type and do each individually. If you just need an additional element for some types, you can probably handle that separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Lars...but...if what you are really looking for is a cool outliner, look no more...I offer you the [Kitchen Sink Outliner](http://jsfiddle.net/KA7NJ/)...with its own kitchen sink scale system ;-)

```
d1 = 30;
d2 = d1 + 5;
```

NOTE:...been working too hard...need some levity...

Comment: Smart idea, to handle the grouping by type / doing each separately *after* the datajoin instead of before.  Although I think you must be making things intentionally confusing by using `d1` and `d2` for your size variables!

Comment: I must admit a certain tongue in cheek...although I should be careful not to make it confusing...it would go against the ultimate objective...I hear you...and appreciate you :-)